# Pipe issue with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been using the following ffmpeg command successfully to extract the first frame of an mp4 file:

```
./ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 -y frame.bmp
```

However, when I try to use the below pipe syntax, I get an error:

```
cat video.mp4 | ./ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -vframes 1 -y frame.bmp
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```
> ffmpeg version 2.4.1-   http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/    Copyright
> (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers   built on Sep 24 2014 18:52:48
> with gcc 4.8 (Debian 4.8.3-11)   configuration: --enable-gpl
> --enable-version3 --disable-shared --disable-debug --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libwebp --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --disable-ffserver --enable-libass --enable-gnutls --cc=gcc-4.8   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101   libavdevice    56.  0.100 /
> 56.  0.100   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100 [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @
> 0x37537e0] stream 0, offset 0x2c: partial file
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x37537e0] Could not find codec parameters
> for stream 1 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), 480x480, 972 kb/s):
> unspecified pixel format Consider increasing the value for the
> 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options Input #0,
> mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:0':   Metadata:
>     major_brand     : mp42
>     minor_version   : 1
>     compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
>     creation_time   : 2014-09-26 09:05:37   Duration: 00:00:02.77, bitrate: N/A
>     Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 61 kb/s (default)
>     Metadata:
>       creation_time   : 2014-09-26 09:05:37
>       handler_name    : Core Media Audio
>     Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), 480x480, 972 kb/s, 24.01 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
>     Metadata:
>       creation_time   : 2014-09-26 09:05:37
>       handler_name    : Core Media Video [buffer @ 0x3742860] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
>     Last message repeated 1 times [buffer @ 0x3742860] Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1. [graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @
> 0x3752d20] Error applying options to the filter. Error opening
> filters!
```

I am using the latest [ffmpeg 64-bit binaries](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong, though I have not used `ffmpeg` much. Two things to try: use `-i /dev/stdin`; also see if `<video.mp4` works instead of piping from `cat`. I have a few wild surmises, and these may help clarify them.

Comment: try `-i -`. that is the standard input.

Comment: So I tried: cat video.mp4 | ./ffmpeg -i /dev/stdin -vframes 1 -y frame.bmp (did not work either), cat video.mp4 | ./ffmpeg -i - -vframes 1 -y frame.bmp (did not work either), ./ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -vframes 1 -y frame.bmp <video.mp4 (did not work either)

Comment: Does it work when you specify `ffmpeg -f mp4 -i - …` to force the format? I can't reproduce it, really.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm hitting the same issue when using a pipe. It does however seem to work fine for videos with moov at the start of the file. I've tried setting analyzeduration and probesize but no luck.

Comment: Just saw Linked question, looks like moving moov to the start of the file will fix things.